# Creating helper "scripts" for JVM based projects

Tags: java, scala, sbt

I'm used to programming in Python. Whenever I create a project, there is usually a `bin/` folder, where various scripts are kept, for example:

- creating the database schema from the ORM
- generating some code (css, javascript, etc.), based on something else
- scripts to graphically visualize some data

**What is the best practice for doing that sort of thing in Scala (and Java).** Custom maven goals, maybe?

I've read, that there are sbt tasks, but they cannot use the compiled libraries of the app itself.

*Update: Here is the place, where it says I cannot use the application code for the build: [sbt Task classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9837191/sbt-task-classpath)*

Comment: Why can't they? I don't know sbt, only Ant/Maven/etc., but they can all use project artifacts. Another common solution is to use batch or shell files.

Comment: and of course, you can write bash scripts with scala syntax, just put those 3 lines at the head of your `.sh` file: `#!/bin/sh`, `exec scala "$0" "$@"`, `!#` and follow it with regular scala syntax.

Comment: @DaveNewton How can it be done with maven?

Comment: I thought `bin` [stands for](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/concepts/bin.html) binary files, not scripts

Comment: @EmilIvanov By using the "exec" plugin; it uses the Maven classpath, which includes the project's artifacts, and dependencies.

Comment: @om-nom-nom IMO `bin` is a canonical location for executables, regardless of implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll shine some light on the java side of things. If you're using Maven, start with a simple project archetype that maven can generate. It will create the directory structure for you and you can start adding things in there. Having a `bin` directory for scripts is perfectly fine. That said, I still prefer to do stuff like schema creation in idiomatic Java instead of having some SQL files that are generated. In my opinion, it's safer and more sustainable long-term. Hibernate, for example, using annotations, will create the DB for you/update it as soon as you initialize a hibernate session so that you don't have to mess with generating a schema and the checking in that sql file to your vcs etc. Maven does have plenty of plugins that may do what you want so that would be the preferred route. If they don't, you can always have maven execute one of your scripts in the `bin` directory.

For example, in my API project, I create/update my Cassandra keyspace and column families when the servlet initializes. This way, you know that your data store will be up-to-date all the time (provided that everyone adds their changes/updates to that init method). This eliminates all the juggling of ... "crap it doesn't work" "...oh that's because you don't have the column families created... get that file from our git... but it may not be up to date so ask CassandraGuy to export the latest schema for you and then import it to your cassandra instance" This doesn't solve every problem. People still need to be disciplined and think about what changes they are making. If someone decides to add an index in init on an existing MySQL table with millions of rows then keep in mind that it will definitely lock that table while init finishes it's index creation... those situations still need code reviews, planning, etc.